# Minecraft wrong FPS

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, performance

I've played a bit with Minecraft Windows 10 edition which is awesome fast and fluid.

I've then tried the demo version of the original game, but it happens to feel laggy.

What I don't understand, is that the FPS counter ingame (F3) shows a nearly constant 60FPS (drop sometimes to 59).

My screen is a 60hz screen, so I don't understand why the game feels so slow.

Is the FPS counter in the game accurate ?

My hardware is a decent laptop Core I7 6700HQ, 16GB of RAM and a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M.

I also tweaked the computer with:

- JVM arguments to increase RAM
- installed latest Java runtime, and made the minecraft launcher use this
- setup in the NVIDIA control panel to use the GPU and not CPU on the javaw process (F3 shows me the correct GPU)

Comment: What else are you running while you play minecraft? Also, do you have any resource packs loaded? This sounds a lot like an issue with your PC, rather than the game.

Comment: @Ben: I'm playing the demo version. But as I said, the game shows 60FPS, but feels more slow than that. I don't ask how to optimize (there are a lot of ressources for that), but why the game seems to be slower than the ingame FPS counter.

Comment: Could you describe how you feel the game is slow? is it slow on responding to input? Are the animations not smooth? could you post a video showing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at your [settings](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Options) specifically the graphics/video ones.  Often small tweeks to these can make a significant difference in lag.

Comment: Thanks, however i didn't ask how to increase framerate (there are dozens of topics for that), but why i feel the game runs at 20 fps even if the ingame counter shows 60 fps)

Comment: The point is if you are seeing lag you should look at changing the video settings as a solution.